# Do I need any extra drivers for the Realtek waves maxx audio on my Dell XPS 17?

Tags: sound, dell

I have a Dell XPS 17(3D) laptop. It has JBL speakers and a subwoofer too.

It came windows pre-installed but I have Linux now in it. The problem is in windows I had Realtek waves maxx audio in it for better audio and stuff, how do I get that driver in Ubuntu 12.04?

Is there any possibility?

Comment: I have the very same Dell L702X laptop and can't get the subwoofer to work at all. I've spent the last week trying everything I found to make ir work, to no avail. Actually the 2 stereo speakers work great, sound is superb. But I can't have the subwoofer to work!!!! no 2.1 at all!! The procedure above will indeed install the ACL665 driver, but that won't enable the subwoofer to work :-( I'm almost giving up on Linux on this particular laptop. The 2.1 sound schema really rocks in Windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found something. There are indeed drivers on the Realtek website. I think they work for all or many of their sound cards. I have a wifi card with a Realtek chip in it, and I had to get something from their website to get it to even work... let me tell you, the native Linux support for Realtek stuff is terrible.

Anyway, the first thing you want to do is download their "Audio Codec Drivers" (Misleadingly named, I believe) from their website ([direct link to the page you want.](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)) Scroll all the way down to the bottom, look under the section labeled "Unix (Linux)" and click on one of the links next to "Linux driver (3.0)". Any link will work but you probably want the one that says "US1" or "US2".

Before you do any of this, make sure that the `build-essential` package is installed.

The next steps: After each command, press the Enter key.

1. Open your trusty Terminal and "cd" to the directory where you have downloaded the .tar.bz2 file. For example, if you put it on your desktop, you want to type `cd ~/Desktop`, or if, say, you put it in your Downloads folder in your Home directory you want to type `cd ~/Downloads`.
2. Then you want to extract it with `tar -xvf LinuxPkg_5.17rc13.tar.bz2`.
3. "cd" into the directory it creates with `cd ./realtek-linux-audiopack-5.17/`.
4. Run the automatic installer script with `sudo ./install`. Type your password and press enter.
5. Now, according to the documentation, everything should run correctly with your sound after you reboot, but just be aware that everything will be muted by default. You can unmute things with your sound management thing on your desktop, but they recommend using the `alsamixer` command (and I also find it to be a very handy utility, especially for fancy sound cards).

I hope that this procedure gets things working for you.

Comment: You also ***might*** have to repeat the process every time you install a new kernel.

Answer (score 3):

The now current **5.18** version `install` introduced a very small bug due to different directory naming which is very easy to correct.

If you run it, it will display errors. So what to do ?

Again, make sure that the `build-essential` package is installed.
Delete the directory *Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18* (just to be shure) and Start again from scratch

1. Open your trusty Terminal and "cd" to the directory where you have downloaded the .tar.bz2 file. For example, if you put it on your desktop, you want to type cd ~/Desktop, or if, say, you put it in your Downloads folder in your Home directory you want to type cd ~/Downloads.
2. Then you want to extract it with `tar -xvf LinuxPkg_5.18.tar.bz2`.
3. "cd" into the directory it creates with `cd ./Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18`.
4. open the `install` script in an editor
5. change line 1  from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` (just to be shure)
6. change line 18 from `cd alsa-driver-RTv5.18` to `cd alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa`
7. Save it and run the automatic installer script with `sudo ./install`. Type your password and press enter.
8. Now, according to the documentation, everything should run correctly with your sound after you reboot, but just be aware that everything will be muted by default. You can unmute things with your sound management thing on your desktop, but they recommend using the alsamixer command.

*(note: I have unshamingly brutally copied >80% of this how-to from @searchfgold6789, except for some details, my apologies for that)*

Comment: Did you get a successful build? I tried, but ended up with a lot of errors. Can you please try building the latest version of realtek drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that if you feel the audio isn't loud enough using the alsamixer, you can download the pulseaudio manager in the Software Center, which will allow you to go beyond 100% and have more granular controls.  I have a Dell XPS L702x, and it works great.