# Drivers for the Realtek waves maxx audio on Dell XPS 15?

Tags: 14.04, sound, dell

Asking a new question for [Do I need any extra drivers for the Realtek waves maxx audio on my Dell XPS 17?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246684/do-i-need-any-extra-drivers-for-the-realtek-waves-maxx-audio-on-my-dell-xps-17)

The solution posted here no longer works for the latest linux kernels (i have 3.16). Does anybody know if it is possible to install the audio drivers?

I am adding the lines from where 'make' command fails.

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-50-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa  CPP="gcc -E" CC="gcc" modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.o
/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c: In function ‘snd_pcm_file_fd’:
/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c:1647:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘fget_light’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  file = fget_light(fd, fput_needed);
  ^
/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c:1647:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  file = fget_light(fd, fput_needed);
       ^
/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c: In function ‘snd_pcm_lib_mmap_iomem’:
/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.c:3453:26: warning: unused variable ‘runtime’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;;
                          ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/pcm_native.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/shikhar/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic'
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```